# Run-time error '5' when using VBA to cycle through PivotTable

Tags: excel, vba, filter, pivot-table

I want to cycle through all options on the "Name" filter and export that info.  It works correctly for the first five and then I get a Run-time error '5': Invalid call or argument at this line:`.PivotFields("Name").CurrentPage = pi.SourceName`

At `MsgBox pi.SourceName` the SourceName correctly updates for the first five records.  Then, for the sixth one, it reverts to the FOURTH record ("ABC Tile, Inc - Parent Modesto, CA") instead of going to "ACE Building Materials", and then I get the Run-time error.

As you'll see, I've tried resetting (and clearing) "Name" to no avail.

Here's the full code:

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Dim pf As PivotField
Dim pi As PivotItem
Dim SourcePivottable As PivotTable
Dim DestinationRange As Range
Dim aCell As Range
Dim myFileName As String
Dim myARName As String

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1")

    .PivotFields("Name").ClearAllFilters

    Set pf = .PivotFields("Name")
    
    For Each pi In pf.PivotItems
    '       .PivotFields("Name").CurrentPage = "(All)"
    MsgBox pi.SourceName
    .PivotFields("Name").CurrentPage = pi.SourceName


    '     Copies Pivot
    Set SourcePivottable = Worksheets("Pivot").PivotTables(1)
    Set DestinationRange = Worksheets("2020 Qtr2").Range("A4")

    SourcePivottable.TableRange1.Copy
    With DestinationRange.Offset( _
    SourcePivottable.TableRange1.Row - SourcePivottable.TableRange2.Row, 0)
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
    End With


    '     Saves file
    wb.SaveAs "I:\filepath\" & myARName & "_" & myFileName & 
    ".xlsx"
    wb.Close
    Workbooks("Generator.xlsm").Activate

    Next
    End With

    End Sub
```

I thought maybe it had to do with how the information was filtered, but that doesn't seem to be the issue.  Any insight would be greatly appreciated!!